# JSF - Faces-config redirect param - howto

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jstl

I'd like to redirect my app flow by using the 'faces-config' xml file resource like as the "redirect" tag.

So, here is my "faces" xml:

```
<navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>falha_etapa_1</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
    <redirect>
      <redirect-param>
        <name>msg</name>
        <value>-1</value>
      </redirect-param>
    </redirect>
  </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

And here, my jsf page:

```
<h:form>
  <f:view>
    <p:outputLabel value="${param['msg']}" />
    and so on....
```

This print's anything (blank)!!!!
Why could not print the parameter value?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to add the bit where you're sending the parameters

Comment: Does it appear in the URL in browser's address bar? If not, then your navigation rule is simply never used. Some code wherein you show how you navigate would be helpful. Don't forget to exclude a dirty deploy from being the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `${param['msg']}` to `#{param['msg']}`

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{param['msg']}" />
```

More info:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0: Implicit EL Objects](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitELObjects)

Comment: In fact, when refreshing the page with the browser debugger, it was possible to check that no params was brought. Some ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you have these params in the form of query string? How are you sure that you have this param in the request?

Comment: Principally, you're right. But technically, it shouldn't matter. The only difference is that `#{}` can do a "setter" operation. But the OP just need a "getter" operation which can as good be done by both. The `#{param}` is an implicit object and doesn't need to be auto-created.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<view-param>` instead of `<redirect-param>`.

Like this:

```
<view-param>
  <name>msg</name>
  <value>-1</value>
</view-param>
```